# MongoDB golang driver not returns unrecognized field `hint` when using hint with CountDocument

Tags: mongodb, go

So I am using the official mongo driver for go `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` and I am running mongodb v4 in a container. All operations work fine but when I try to add a hint to CountDocument it fails with an error saying `unrecognized field hint`. I have seen this error reported in old gh issues and jira threads but the problem in those cases was that people were using mongo versions older than 3.6 but I am using v4 so I can't figure out the problem.

```
opts := &options.CountOptions{}
opts.SetHint("client_1_created_at_1")

count, err := r.collection.CountDocuments(ctx, query, opts)
if err != nil {
    return 0, err
}
return count, nil
```

MongoDB version: 4.0.6
Mongo Driver version: 1.0.1

Comment: Hey would you be able to make a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and send that our way on the jira thread (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-1156)?

Please recreate the issue using the master thread version of the driver

Answer (score 0):

`CountDocuments()` in mongo-go-driver follows mongo shell `countDocuments()` practice, which is an `aggregate` of `$match` and `$group`. You won't be able to use hint on `aggregate`.

See the implementation [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.0.3/x/network/command/count_documents.go#L43). The `SetHint()` option is misleading and still there by mistake I think.

Side note: should trust query planner, as long as you have an appropriate index, mongo query planner will pickup the right index for you.